# Android 64 bit architecture support

Tags: android, google-play, x86-64

As many of you know Aug 2019 onwards Google is making sure all apps are supported 64 bit architecture.https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

That brings up the point to support 64 bit architectures for arm and x86. For x86 I think no devices are available. It's only emulators who has x86 support.

My application uses some native code. So my question is if my application is 64 bit compatible for arm and not for 86. Does google accepts my updates? Doe not providing x86_64 *.so files means I am dropping support of x86?

Comment: "For x86 I think no devices are available" -- there are millions of Chrome OS devices that are powered by x86 CPUs. There are fairly few x86 phones, though. "Does google accepts my updates?" -- [ask Google](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Just add the line `ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64','armeabi','mips'` in your app level gradle to also support 64 bit.

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64','armeabi','mips'

    }
}
```