# What is Support 64-bit architectures

Tags: android

I have app and I built it 2 years ago by Java language and one of my customer asked me does the app support Support 64-bit architectures or I must do something for support that ?

*I saw that*

> Assess your app If your app uses only code written in the Java
>   programming language or Kotlin, including all libraries or SDKs, your
>   app is already ready for 64-bit devices. If your app uses any native
>   code, or you are unsure if it does, you will need to assess your app
>   and take action.

My question is do I should add/edit something or no for support it ?

Comment: If its just Java and no third party libraries which use NDK files, no action need to be taken. If you are concerned you can follow the documentation: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 64 bit architecture support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56836071/android-64-bit-architecture-support)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for 64-bit architectures is *required* as of **August 1, 2019**.

As the quote you posted suggests, your app already supports 64-bit architectures if you are using only the Java or Kotlin programming languages in your application, and thus **nothing else needs to be done**.

If your application uses the NDK/native code in any way, including through third party libraries, you'll need to ensure you meet the new requirements by targeting the correct architectures and/or ensuring authors of any third party libraries you are using support 64-bit architectures.

A great way to check whether your app includes libraries using native code is through the [APK Analyzer](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#apk-analyzer).

Further reading on this topic, including how to meet the new 64-bit requirements, can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit).